# How can I get the URL of the request sender to my API?

Tags: python, angular, flask, httpclient

I'm trying to secure my API routes with API keys and website URL of the client.
I'm using the tuple `(api_key, website_url)` to grant the access to my API. In fact, the website URL is sent in the request. Example: using Angular httpClient

```
this.restPost(this.endpoint,body,options)
```

the options include: the API key and website URL.

How can I check if the `website_url` inserted in the options matches the URL of the request sender? I'm using Flask microframework in the backend.

Comment: If you could independently validate the URL the request was coming from, why would you need it in the options at all? You could use the Referer header, but that can be spoofed. This is fundamentally not secure.

Comment: What about a mobile or desktop app that uses your API? It won't have a URL at all.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the fast response. Can you give me another way to secure the API routes ?

Comment: @DanielPryden, what is the best practice in my case ?

Comment: @DanielPryden , cause using only API key to grant access is not secure. Anyone have the API key can access to the API . How can I differ between the users that I provided them with API key and the users that I didn't ?

Comment: You need to provide each API client with its own API key and then monitor carefully the requests coming in with that key. You could do something stronger like a client side TLS certificate, but still nothing prevents your clients from sharing the certificate you give them with someone else.

Comment: @DanielPryden thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is impossible.

Fundamentally, if requests are coming to you across the public internet, you *cannot* know the identity of the application sending requests to you.

You can make an educated guess about the remote client. But since the remote client is running on a platform you can't control, nothing prevents an attacker from reverse engineering how it works and then sending you identical requests. You won't be able to tell the difference if the attacker is skilled enough.

There are tools that can help you detect and block malicious clients, but there are also tools for malicious clients to evade detection (just search Stack Overflow for many examples of the reverse problem). It's an arms race and if you want to win you will need to invest more time and money than your counterpart(s) on the other side are.

The normal solution to this problem is to make it your clients' problem. Charge them for a quota of API requests, and bill them if they make more than that. Then if they share the API key with someone else, they also need to pay the bill for them. Then you don't need to care whose API key it is: you're getting paid either way.

If you can't bill them (e.g. if it's a free service) then the next best thing is rate limiting. Don't allow more than, say, 10 requests in a second for a single API key.

If you're serious about this sort of thing, you probably don't want to reinvent the wheel. There are cloud-scale API gateway services out there. Pick one and use it to handle all your API key authentication and client throttling.